# Why I am getting corrupted files by downloading it via file_get_contents?

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

```
    $source_path = 'https://bip.wzp.pl/attachments/' . $filename;  


    $opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Content-type: application/pdf",
      )
    );

   $context = stream_context_create($opts);    

    $data = file_get_contents($source_path, false, $context);

    if(($handle = fopen($dest_path, "w"))) {
        fwrite($handle, $data);
        fclose($handle);
        return $filename_converted;
    }
```

`$source_path` is e.g:

> https://bip.wzp.pl/attachments/28172_Statut Województwa
>   Zachodniopomorskiego.pdf

When I trying it browser, a pdf document displayes properly.

But downloaded file via PHP, it is always corrupted.

**EDIT**

I checked `$data` content. It has front page html :/
It strange putting `$source_path` to browser returns pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you try to download a PDF, try saving it as a binary file using:

```
fopen($dest_path, "wb")
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is quite different, instead of pdf content in $data I have home pagee html :/

Comment: I tried urlencode on $filename before, but it changed my URL and I gets always front page instead of pdf in browser.

Comment: @JohnP I use the "wb" but still getting the corrupted file.